# Defining a Range Based on Cell Color and a String

Tags: excel, vba, module

I am wanting to make a range of all cells in C4:Z104 that contain a letter AND either has a color index of white or grey (2 or 15 or 16). There are cells with other colors that should not be included in the range. Note that the cells are non-numeric.

Below is code that I'm trying to debug. It throws an error. I've tried using IsEmpty(), but read on other threads that this may not be the best for string values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SelectByColorAndString()
  Dim cell As Range, u As Boolean
  For Each cell In Range("C4:Z104")
    
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 or cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 or  cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 or & Not (IsNumeric(cell.Value) then
      If u = False Then cell.Select:  u = True
      Range(Selection.Address & "," & cell.Address).Select
    
End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Also, if any cell in any one of these 100 rows is included, the range should include the string value that is in column 1 of that row.

Thank you,
MST

I've tried the following code but am receiving an error. I wanted all cells that are white or grey that have a letter in them to be selected.

```
Sub SelectByColorAndString()
  Dim cell As Range, u As Boolean
  For Each cell In Range("C4:Z104")
    
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 or cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 or  cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 or & Not (IsNumeric(cell.Value) then
      If u = False Then cell.Select:  u = True
      Range(Selection.Address & "," & cell.Address).Select
    
End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA uses `And` not `&` for boolean logic, and you need some parentheses around the tests for fill color.

Try this:

```
Sub SelectByColorAndString()
    Dim cell As Range, u As Boolean, ci As Long, rng As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C4:Z104").Cells
        ci = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
        If (ci = 2 Or ci = 15 Or ci = 16) And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = cell
            Else
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. I will study your code. Ultimately, I want to output the cell text values of this range along with some reference data in column A and put it into an email to several people. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried running this code and it appears to not create the range. I've tried tweaking it a bit, such as removing the nested IF, and it does not create the range. Any other suggestions or revisions to select all cells with text values and the white or grey fill? Thanks

Comment: Wow, it does indeed work. I just realized that the white color index value of 2 is not the same as the default "white" background of the cells. When I filled the cells white, it works. Thanks again Tim.

Comment: A cell with no fill (not the same as a cell with a white fill) has a ColorIndex = `xlNone` so you can test for cells with no fill using that value.

Comment: Thank you Tim. For my if statement, I ended up using If (ci = -4142 Or ci = 2 Or ci = 15 Or ci = 16) And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value). I suppose I could've substituted xlNone in place of -4142. Thanks again.